nslcd myldap_bind(): binddn buffer too small
Host with OS
Linux 5.4.17-2102.201.3.el8uek.x86_64

For user authentication use nslcd service
# nslcd -V
nss-pam-ldapd 0.9.9

config:
# cat /etc/nslcd.conf
uid nslcd
gid ldap
uri ldap://ldap.home.com
base dc=home,dc=com
binddn uid=nssproxy,ou=People,dc=home,dc=com
bindpw Fgsdf1s
scope sub
ssl no
tls_cacertdir /etc/openldap/certs
map    shadow userPassword     userPassword

some users after try ssh connection return
nslcd[920153]: [e2c8ba] <authc="nauser01"> myldap_bind(): binddn buffer too small (571 required)

How solve this problem?
